# Absolute position of item relative to multiple line span

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a div that contains some text. On some of the words/sentences I would like it so that people can click, and a little pop-up comes up with a more detailed explanation or something like that.

Right now it looks something like this without the pop-up:

[image]

And when clicked I get this:

[image]

The entire teal text is created as a component with the HTML:

```
<span (click)="toggleReveal()" [class.is-active]="reveal">
  some text that creates a popup, and it might be a bit long as well
  <div><img src="my_blurry_image.jpg" alt=""></div>
</span>
```

Where `div` have `position: absolute` and `span` `position: relative`. The `span` contains the text, and the div is the actual pop-up. The problem, as can be seen, is that even though the span actually spans across the entire parent div (on the second line) the absolute position is based on the top line. And even if the top line is the entire span of the div, it will also position itself according to the line below if that is short, e.g.:

[image]

I know I could just make the span `display: block`, but that will result in the before and after text (not teal) to be placed on another line, and breaking the sentence.

So is there anything I can do here to make it position itself according to the longest line-span, or...?

Comment: parent div has position value? try adding one.

Comment: do you want it to move with the text as it scroll? One thing to do is to use javascript to position the popup

Comment: Ideally it should just stay in place even when scrolling. I have never tried using JS for this. Because, and that is also a concern, if the item is short, and e.g. far left, and the pop-up is wide, then it will go outside the view port as well. Can all of this be fixed with JS ?

Comment: does my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good thing to do is add a `<br>` infront of the link everytime it is pressed via javascript.

Eventhough this probably isn't the best way it should work.

`document.createElement('<br />');`